# Issue while trying to configure outgoing mail server

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I tried setting up the outgoing server with the following credentials:

SMTP Server : smtp.office365.com, SMTP Port : 25, Connection Security :TLS (STARTTLS), Username : ***, Password : ***

The Test connection is successful, but my outgoing mail is failed with the following message:

Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'smtp.office365.com'.
SMTPDataError: 554
5.2.252 SendAsDenied

Any clue will be helpful..

Comment: Your information seem contradictory to me. Is it google or office365 smtp?

Comment: @CZoellner Its office365 smtp

Comment: something to read: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/44943

Comment: @CZoellner github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/44943 This is not relatable to my issue.

Comment: Seems to me, the issue has something to do with it. Basic Authentication was permanently disabled on 23.01.2023 (i know of one case myself). Odoo 10 has no 2FA implementation for Microsoft Services, so it can't work without some customization.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set right configurations for outgoing SMTP server based on [Google guides](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp).

> The outgoing SMTP server, smtp.gmail.com, supports TLS. If your client
> begins with plain text, before issuing the STARTTLS command, use port
> `465` (for SSL), or port `587` (for TLS).

Comment: Its not google account. Its office365

Comment: So why you have inserted SMTP server for Gmail: `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: Try to set SMTP port number **587** instead of 25.

Comment: Tried. Still facing same issue